# Calculadora de factorial y sumatoria de n numeros me da resultados incorrectos

Tags: c

Algunos valores que me arrojan resultados extraños = números mayores a 31, 25, 24 etc. En unos me dan números negativos y en el caso de cualquier numero mayor a 31 me da solo -1 
alguien que me ayude!!

//¢ Se tienen varios números enteros, elaborar una solución algorítmica para que los 300 números que se introduzcan entre 1 y 100 hagan lo siguientes: 
    //a)    Menores o iguales a 30 calcular su factorial
    //b)    Para los que no, mostrar la sumatoria de los enteros que hay de uno hasta dichos números

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int fact (int k)
{
    int result,w;
    result=1;
    for (w=k; w>=1;w--)
    {
        result=result*w;
    }
    return result;  
}

int sum (int k)
{
    int sumatoria,w,p;
    sumatoria=k;
    w=1;
    for (p=1;p<sumatoria;p++)
    {
        w=w+(w+1);
    }
    return w;
}

int main ()
{
    int cant,num,c;

    printf("INGRESE CANTIDAD DE NUMEROS A INGRESAR\n");
    scanf("%d",&cant);

    for (c=0;c<cant;c++)
    {
        printf("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD #%d (1-100)\n",c+1);
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if (num <= 30)
        {
            printf("NUMERO INGRESADO MENOR O IGUAL A 30\n");
            printf("FACTORIAL=%d\n",fact(num));
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NUMERO MAYOR A 30\n");
            printf("SUMATORIA=%d\n",sum(num));
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>




long fact (long k)
{
    long result,w;
    result=1;
    for (w=k; w>=1;w--)
    {
        result=result*w;
    }
    return result;
}

long sum (int k)
{
    long sumatoria,w,p;
    sumatoria=k;
    w=1;
    for (p=1;p<sumatoria;p++)
    {
        w=w+(w+1);
        printf("pruebita=%ld\n",w);

    }
    return w;


}

int main ()
{
    long cant,num,c;

    printf("INGRESE CANTIDAD DE NUMEROS A INGRESAR\n");
    scanf("%ld",&cant);

    for (c=0;c<cant;c++)
    {
        printf("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD #%ld (1-100)\n",c+1);
        scanf("%ld",&num);
        if (num <= 30)
        {
            printf("NUMERO INGRESADO MENOR O IGUAL A 30\n");
            printf("FACTORIAL=%ld\n",fact(num));
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NUMERO MAYOR A 30\n");
            printf("SUMATORIA=%ld\n",sum(num));
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Por lo que vi, una vez que overflowdea te tira -1, lo que hice fue cambiarle el tipo de dato por long (es un int mas grande), aclaración, esto es C y no C++!